# AutoCAD to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

Hi How can I access a spreadsheet from AutoCad and take a value from there and use it on AutoCAd
Here is my code but it does not get the value , it's always empty. Don't know what's wrong

```
Sub move()
Dim EXCELApplication As Object
Dim ExcelWorksheet As Object

Set EXCELApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
EXCELApplication.workbooks.Open AcadToExcel
EXCELApplication.Visible = True
Set ExcelWorksheet = EXCELApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

modelsize = ExcelWorksheet.Cells(21, 3).Value

Size = modelsize

End Sub
```

Comment: You `Dim EXCELApplication`  but you never SET it to anything.

Comment: I edited that but it still does not return a value

Comment: What is the value of `AcadToExcel` ? Where are you learning how to do this? Your code is very incomplete.

Comment: The value is dynamic, It changes .. this is not all the code but this is the part of the code that is supposed to give me the value

Comment: okay, how do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this and it works just fine for me:

```
Public Sub GetFromExcel()
  Dim sFile As String
  sFile = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\Test2.xlsx"
  Dim EXCELApplication As Object
  Dim ExcelWorksheet As Object
  Dim sValue As String

  Set EXCELApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  EXCELApplication.workbooks.Add sFile
  EXCELApplication.Visible = True
  Set ExcelWorksheet = EXCELApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

  sValue = ExcelWorksheet.Range("A1").Value

  MsgBox sValue

End Sub
```

If it doesnt work for you, then the problem is your filename.

Comment: This works but the problem is that the spreadsheet I want it to take the value from is open already, now what the code does is to open a new spreadsheet and it doesn't have the value, how can I go about this?

Comment: Look into `GetObject(,"Excel.Application")` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, should I specify my specific spreadsheet there or what? How can I write a "ActiveWorkbook" syntax that works

Comment: Dont use `ActiveWorkbook` - Once you have your `Application` object, parse the `WorkBooks` collection for name of the WorkBook you are looking for.

Comment: It just opens another workbook and names it "AcadToExcel1", when I run it again it opens and names as "AcadToExcel2" etc...I do not know how to remedy this

Comment: Use `Open` instead of `Add` then, or you could use `Instr` to check for "AcadToExcel" existing in the Workbook name.

Comment: How do I close the workbook using AutoCAD `EXCELApplication.workbooks.Close sFile` gives me an error

Comment: You dont close the `Workbooks` collection, you close the `Workbook`.